# What's the lifecycle of a Tropico citizen?

Tags: tropico-3

Here's a simple question that I just have not been able to eyeball - What's the life-cycle of a citizen in Tropico? As in:

- At what age are they babies?
- At what age are they children (and does a grade school affect this)?
- At what age are they able to attend high school/get a job?
- At what age can Tropicans get married?
- At what age can women become mothers?
- At what age do they retire?

I can't find anything anywhere that has even basic information about Tropican life-cycles!

Comment: probably because none of this information matters to actually playing the game.